# R ggplot label gets cutoff on very small values

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a graph that is generated via loop, so solution has to be dynamic and not a once off.

Basically its all fine, until there is a dataset that has extremes. In this case, a geom_col where the first two bars are ~16k and ~6k and the third bar is only 2. Because its barely above the 0 the number "2" gets cutoff. Being a dynamically generated graph, I can't use position to move it above the bars, or the higher numbers get cut off.
[image]

```
ggplot(gndr_cnt_tbl, aes(Var1, Freq, fill=Var1)) +
  geom_col() +
  geom_text(aes(label=Freq), position=position_stack(0.5), size = 5) + theme(legend.position = "none", axis.text=element_text(size=15), axis.title=element_text(size=12))+ggtitle("Gender Breakdown")+
  theme(plot.title = element_text(size=15))+xlab("Gender")+   scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0, 0), limits = c(0, NA))
```

Any help would be great :)

Answer (score 2):

Here are two approaches.

1. Shift the y value of your labels if they're too low. Here, `pmax(1000, Freq)` places the text at the larger value of Freq or 1000, putting a lower bound on the text location.

Code:

```
ggplot(gndr_cnt_tbl, aes(Var1, Freq, fill=Var1)) +
  geom_col() +
  geom_text(aes(label=Freq, y = pmax(1000, Freq)),   # HERE
            position=position_stack(0.5), size = 5) + 
  theme(legend.position = "none", axis.text=element_text(size=15), 
        axis.title=element_text(size=12))+ggtitle("Gender Breakdown")+
  theme(plot.title = element_text(size=15))+xlab("Gender")+   
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0, 0), limits = c(0, NA))
```

[image]

2. Add  `+ coord_cartesian(clip = "off")` so that text and plot elements outside the plot area are not clipped away. If you want to keep the value from overlapping your axis labels, you could additionally shift the vertical alignment with `vjust = 0`.

[image]

Sample data I used:

```
gndr_cnt_tbl = data.frame(
  Var1 = c("Female", "Male", "Other"),
  Freq = c(10000, 5000, 5)
)
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks! and extra thanks for adding both options!